# Getting the changed type of files and the previous version in HG

Tags: svn, mercurial

I am currently collecting some information using the commit logs generated for HG and SVN.

SVN Sample:

---

r1667884 | kschenk | 2015-03-20 05:37:55 +0800 (Fri, 20 Mar 2015) | 1 line

**#126118# Fix malformed if statements in makefile.**

Hg Sample:

---

**changeset:   276992:8b564af029aa

bookmark:    writercompare01

tag:         tip

parent:      266455:8565218dc235

user:        thb@openoffice.org

date:        Fri Mar 19 00:16:57 2010 +0100

summary:     CWS writercompare01: #i110237# the changes from Tzvetelina as-is**

I would like to know the followings:

1. If the above commit infor is related to the diff of two revisions, which revision is displayed as the  Revision (in svn 1667884) Id and Changeset(Hg 276992:8b564af029aa) Id. Is it the revision before it is committed or the revision id after committed? If it is the second one how to get the related previous revision in svn and HG? can I use **hg diff -c changesetid** to get the previous version?
2. When considering the changeset is the first numerical portion considered as the revision id?
3. Is there any command which I could use to get the changed type (modified, deleted, ignored and etc. ex: "**M** /openoffice/trunk/main/vcl/Module_vcl.mk"
   ) in HG together with the files changed for each commit as given above?

Thank you
dr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm talking mercurial here:

**ad 2)**
The changeset ID (referred to by the globally unique hash **or** the only locally valid numeric ID) indicates a set of changes. Thus if you checkout your repository with revision 276992:8b564af029aa then it includes the repository with all changes, including the one made by that very changeset.

**ad 1)**
I consider it unfortunate terminology,but you seem to call it 'the revision id after commit'.

You can use mercurials revset terminology to walk the history. If it is the previous commit you are interested, and the output of `hg diff -c changesetID` suits you, use `hg diff -c changesetID^` instead (mind the trailing ^). See also `hg help revset`

**ad 3)**
Here again, mercurials templating engine is very powerful: see `hg help templates` on how to custom-tailor the log output as you need it - it allows excellent fine-tuning. If the output of `hg log -rXXX --stat` is insufficient for you, I'd suggest for your case to use a template like:

`hg log -rXXX --template="{file_adds % 'A {file}\n'}{file_mods % 'M {file}\n}{file_dels, 'R {file}\n'}"`

where XXX is the changesetID you want to query; it mimics the output of `hg st`. Maybe additionally also make use of `file_copies` in the template. Mind that the concept of "ignored files" doesn't make much sense when investigating a changeset instead of the state of your working directory. If you want a list of all files which constitute a certain revision, changed or not changed, there is `hg manifest` for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I think I have got the necessary answers.